# Saving set of data into excel file

Tags: python, excel, pandas

im trying to save an output that i have calculated using python pandas, i have used tabulate to organize the output, but when im writing the output into an excel file, it won't open, and error message from excel appears, i have opened the file using text book and the output was correct

writer = open(file='Company.xlsx',mode='w')
writer.writelines(tabulate(result))

[this is the output when using text file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uz6vr.png)

[this is the error message from excel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OrKG9.png)

Comment: Use a library for writing to Excel files, such as xlsxwriter or openpyxl.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.